# Retrieve the value of a variable that stores in local storage the options chosen by users in a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, global-variables

I need to retrieve the value of a variable that stores in local storage the options chosen by users in a dropdown list in order to use it elsewhere.

This is the code, the dropdown has a list of years from 2020 to the current year.

I store the year in local storage on change and in Chrome Dev Tools you can see how the stored variable changes when other years are chosen from the dropdown.

So far so good. But when I try to retrieve the year in the userSelectedYearStorage variable the last console.log line won't show. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
    <body>
      <div id="app">
        <select id="yearSelection">
          <option value="0" selected>Select a year</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    
          <script>
    
            var yearSelection = document.getElementById("yearSelection");
            var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
            for (let y = 2020; y <= currentYear; y++) {
              var element = document.createElement("option");
              element.textContent = y;
              element.value = y;
              yearSelection.appendChild(element);
            }
        
            var userSelectedYear = 0;
            $("#yearSelection").on("change", function () {
              userSelectedYear = this.value;
              console.log("userSelectedYear inside on change: " + userSelectedYear);
              localStorage.setItem("userSelectedYear", userSelectedYear);
            });
        
            var userSelectedYearStorage = localStorage.getItem('userSelectedYear')
//this line below won't be printed:
            console.log("userSelectedYear outside on change: " + userSelectedYearStorage);
        
          </script>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when the page is first loaded, `localStorage.getItem('userSelectedYear')` equals `null` (it is not yet set). It only gets set when the change event is triggered. You can fix this by giving `userSelectedYearStorage` a default value like so

```
// userSelectedYear defaults to 0
var userSelectedYearStorage = localStorage.getItem('userSelectedYear') ?? userSelectedYear;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I have tried your code and this is what happens: in Chrome Dev Tools you can see in the local storage how the value of userSelectedYear changes when different years are selected. So far so good. But when in the console I try userSelectedYearStorage, its value doesn't change, it stays with the value it had when the page loaded. In the Firefox tools console userSelectedYearStorage returns 0. What is happening?

Comment: That's exactly how it's supposed to work in the console. Variables are not reactive in JavaScript by default. If you want to get the new value in the console, you can enter `localStorage.getItem('userSelectedYear')` or `userSelectedYear`.

Answer (score 0):

The last console.log is reading only when the page load the onload event of your body then if you trigged the event from the dropdown this console.log is never read.